# Clustering/Similarity between text cells in an postgres aggregate

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, group-by, count

I've got a table that has a text column and some other identifying features. I want to be able to group by one of the features and find out whether the text in the groups are similar or not. I want to use this to determine if there are multiple groups in my data or a single group (with some possible bad spelling) so that I can provide a rough "confidence" value showing if the aggregate represents a single group or not.

```
CREATE TABLE data_test (
Id serial primary key,
Name VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
Job VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO data_test
    (Name, Job)
VALUES
    ('John', 'Astronaut'),
    ('John', 'Astronaut'),
    ('Ann', 'Sales'),
    ('Jon', 'Astronaut'),
    ('Jason', 'Sales'),
    ('Pranav', 'Sales'),
    ('Todd', 'Sales'),
    ('John', 'Astronaut');
```

I'd like to run a query that was something like:

```
select 
  Job,
  count(Name),
  Similarity_Agg(Name)
from data_test
group by Job;
```

and receive

```
Job        count   Similarity 
Sales      4       0.1 
Astronaut  4       0.9
```

Basically showing that Astronaut names are very similar (or, more likely in my data, all the rows are referring to a single astronaut) and the Sales names aren't (more people working in sales than in space). I see there is a [Postgres Module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/pgtrgm.html) that can handle comparing two strings but it doesn't seem to have any aggregate functions in it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is a self-join:

```
select 
    d.job,
    count(distinct d.id) cnt,
    avg(similarly(d.name, d1.name)) avg_similarity
from data_test d
inner join data_test d1 on d1.job = d.job
group by d.job
```

Comment: This looks promising... just to check my understanding, the self join is going to result in n^2 cost on calculating the pg_trgm similarity? It shouldn't be a problem in most cases since my data will have 2 or 3 items in the group in most cases with about 1k in a handful.

Comment: I think `min` would be a better aggregate than `avg` for the usage of deciding if the group is homogeneous.

Comment: It works. I'm also thinking that using a median or min instead of average might be a better idea but it depends on the use case I'm looking at. Basically  anything that's not a 1 is a cause for concern.